# Is the dualizing sheaf on a product $X \times Y$ just $\pi_X^* \omega_X \otimes \pi_Y^* \omega_Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be (possibly singular) projective schemes over a field $k$ (I'm also willing to assume $k$ algebraically closed or even $k = \mathbb C$). I would like to know if
$$ \omega_{X \times Y} = \pi_X^* \omega_X \otimes \pi_Y^* \omega_Y,$$
where $\omega_X$ etc are the dualizing sheaves.

If both $X$ and $Y$ are smooth of dimension $r$ and $s$, then $X \times Y$ is smooth of dimension $r + s$ and so $$\omega_{X \times Y} = \Lambda^{r+s} \Omega_{X \times Y} = \Lambda^{r + s} (\pi_X^* \Omega_X \oplus \pi_Y^* \Omega_Y) = (\Lambda^r \pi_X^*\Omega_X) \otimes (\Lambda^s \pi_Y^*\Omega_Y) = \pi_X^* \omega_X \otimes \pi_Y^* \omega_Y.$$

But what about the general case?

I thought a bit about using the characterization
$$\omega_X = \mathcal{Ext}^r_{\mathbb{P}^n}(\mathcal{O}_X, \omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}),$$
where $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ is a closed embedding. But then I have to embed the product via the Segre embedding
$$ X \times Y \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{nm + n + m}$$
and I don't have any clue how to relate the different $\mathcal{Ext}$-sheaves in this situation.

Comment: This is true on the level of dualizing complexes, and a proof should be available via the standard material in Hartshorne's *Residues and Duality*. A key step would be reducing the verification to the affine case via lemma II.7.16, where you're trying to show that $$\operatorname{RHom}(k[x]/I,k[x])\otimes\operatorname{RHom}(k[y]/J,k[y])\cong \operatorname{RHom}(k[x,y]/(I,J),k[x,y])$$ in the derived category. Sorry for not writing a full answer at the moment, but I hope this is at least a little helpful.